# How can I install a system app that I uninstalled?

Tags: installation, system-apps

I used a backup app to first make a backup of the `.apk` file of the system app, and then uninstalled it. When I try installing it again, I get "application not installed".

How can I go about that? I don't know in which place the `.apk` was stored originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you put the APK back to where you deleted it from. As in your case you didn't check that (but used a backup app to extract it), that "original place" usually is `/system/priv-app`. Check the structure in that directory (it differs between Android versions), then place your `.apk` accordingly. After that, don't forget to reboot – as only after that the APK will be loaded.

Note (you know that but others might miss it): in order to write to `/system` you need to mount it read-write first:

```
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
# do the copy here
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

As you have to reboot anyway, you can skip the last step as the boot process then takes care for it.